# IBackgroundTask with IDisposables

Tags: c#, uwp, idisposable

If I have a UWP background task (implementation of IBackgroundTask), and the class contains disposable members, where shall I dispose them? I can make the class also implement IDisposable, but the runtime interacts with it through the IBackgroundTask interface so I doubt it would ever call dispose. Would I need to manually dispose at the end of Run() and also in the Canceled handler? Or...?

Comment: As you said, you can dispose members at the end of Run() method but before `_deferral.Complete();`, when the background task completes, dispose them. And also need to dispose them in its Canceled event, when the background task cancels, stop work.

Comment: By the way, if there are no async methods and only Run(), is deferral still needed? MSDN explains deferral as needed to keep the task alive for async operations after Run() exits, yet most online example code has deferral used in Run() itself...

Comment: I mean specifically async methods that are not awaited in Run() (otherwise if awaited then of course Run() would persist until they're done)

Comment: If `Run` is entirely synchronous, no you don't need a deferral. What objects are you trying to `Dispose`? If the process is about to die anyway, it's moot.

Comment: What do you mean entirely synchronous? If an async call is awaited inside Run(), would that also avoid the need for a deferral since Run() has not yet completed?
I'm trying to Dispose a logger.

Comment: Also, is it necessary to complete a deferral if throwing an exception from Run() (as to get an error in the Windows vent log)?

Comment: deferral is used to handle asynchronous tasks or time-consuming tasks. If they are synchronous methods, you don't need a deferral. When you catch an exception and don't want to continue, you can add a deferral to end this task.

Comment: Thanks. What I mean is, I want to log and *rethrow* the exception (since I do want the task to crash with appropriate error showing up in the event log). My question is, throwing the exception out of Run() is a deferral completion still necessary (so deferral.complete() before the throw)

Comment: If you want to throw the exception, you could try to call deferral.complete() before throw. In that case, what issue have you encountered?

Comment: Doesn't the task risk being terminated as soon as deferral is completed? In that case it may not reach the following throw statement and thus I'll miss the exception

Comment: By testing, when declare the deferral complete, it means the asynchronous code completes. And it will continue and reach the throw statement below it.

Comment: Thanks. One last thing is a bit unrelated but you might know: since there's no UI thread in background tasks does this mean that there's no synchronization context and an await from Run() will always behave as if configureAwait(false) and not return to the original thread? This matters to me as I'm calling into a non-thread-safe native library on either sides of awaits

Comment: You can use your own native library to test. According to the information we look for, the background task is a separate process and there is no return value. There should be no original thread.